# Alter table add column not null on empty table in netezza

Tags: netezza

```
SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> create table test ( name varchar(20), age int);

CREATE TABLE

SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> alter table test add column dob varchar(20) NOT NULL;
```

ERROR:  ALTER TABLE: not null constraint for column "DOB" not allowed without default value

Do we have to specify a default value after not null even on empty table?

```
SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> alter table test add column dob varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0';
ALTER TABLE
```

Is this expected behavior ?

Answer (score 4):

You can create the table from scratch without specifying a default value.

```
create table test ( name varchar(20)
, age int
,dob varchar(20) NOT NULL );
```

However when adding a column it is required in postgresql (netezza) to specify a default value to fill any nulls that would be present.  This is expected.  The sequence to remove the default is as follows:

```
 create table test ( name varchar(20), age int);
 ALTER TABLE test add column dob varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'a';
 ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN dob DROP DEFAULT;
```

[How can I add a column to a Postgresql database that doesn't allow nulls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512451/how-can-i-add-a-column-to-a-postgresql-database-that-doesnt-allow-nulls)

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is expected. When altering a table, Netezza uses a versioned table approach. If you add a column to a table, there will actually be two different table versions under the covers which are presented as a single table to the user.

The original table version (the one without the new NOT NULL DEFAULT column) is not modified until a GROOM VERSIONS collapses the versions again into a single underlying table. The upside here is that the alter is fast because it doesn't require a scan/update of the existing rows. Instead it knows to provide the DEFAULT value for column that doesn't exist in the original underlying table version.

When altering a table to add a column with the NOT NULL property, the system *requires* a DEFAULT specification so that it knows how to represent the added column. This is required whether the table actually has any rows or not.

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> CREATE TABLE TEST ( NAME VARCHAR(20), AGE INT);
CREATE TABLE
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> insert into test values ('mine',5);
INSERT 0 1
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> ALTER TABLE TEST ADD COLUMN DOB VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0';
ALTER TABLE
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> insert into test values ('yours',50);
INSERT 0 1
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select* from test;
 NAME  | AGE | DOB
-------+-----+-----
 yours |  50 | 0
 mine  |   5 | 0
(2 rows)
```

The good news is that you can then alter the newly added column to remove that default.

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> ALTER TABLE TEST ALTER COLUMN DOB DROP DEFAULT;
ALTER TABLE
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> \d test
                         Table "TEST"
 Attribute |         Type          | Modifier | Default Value
-----------+-----------------------+----------+---------------
 NAME      | CHARACTER VARYING(20) |          |
 AGE       | INTEGER               |          |
 DOB       | CHARACTER VARYING(20) | NOT NULL |
Distributed on random: (round-robin)
Versions: 2

TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select * from test;
 NAME  | AGE | DOB
-------+-----+-----
 yours |  50 | 0
 mine  |   5 | 0
(2 rows)
```

As a parting note, it's important to groom any versioned tables as promptly as possible in order to keep your performance from degrading over time due to the nature of versioned tables.

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> GROOM TABLE TEST VERSIONS;
NOTICE:  Groom will not purge records deleted by transactions that started after 2015-07-27 01:32:16.
NOTICE:  If this process is interrupted please either repeat GROOM VERSIONS or issue 'GENERATE STATISTICS ON "TEST"'
NOTICE:  Groom processed 1 pages; purged 0 records; scan size unchanged; table size unchanged.
GROOM VERSIONS
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> \d test
                         Table "TEST"
 Attribute |         Type          | Modifier | Default Value
-----------+-----------------------+----------+---------------
 NAME      | CHARACTER VARYING(20) |          |
 AGE       | INTEGER               |          |
 DOB       | CHARACTER VARYING(20) | NOT NULL |
Distributed on random: (round-robin)
```

At this point the table is no longer a versioned table an all values for the NOT NULL columns are fully materialized.