# How to alter new not null column in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-null

I have a table that I want to add new `not null varchar(255)` column

My query is:

```
alter table poll_management.DASHLETS add column name varchar(255) not null;
update poll_management.DASHLETS as dashlet set name = report.name 
from poll_management.REPORTS as report
WHERE dashlet.id = report.reportdashletid
```

But I have an error:

```
ERROR:  column "name" contains null values
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "name" contains null values
SQL state: 23502
```

Comment: either add column with null, then update values and alter to not null, or add column not null default 'somevalue';

Comment: You have added "name" column as not null and as per the error it says that in report table some values of "name" column is null.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add a column that doesn't allow nulls in a Postgresql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512451/how-can-i-add-a-column-that-doesnt-allow-nulls-in-a-postgresql-database)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid your error, two solutions come at once:

```
BEGIN;
  alter table poll_management.DASHLETS add column name varchar(255);
  update poll_management.DASHLETS as dashlet set name = report.name 
from poll_management.REPORTS as report;
  --mind I removed where, cos you need to update ALL rows to have some avlue
  alter table poll_management.DASHLETS alter column "name" set not null;
END;
```

and the other:

```
  alter table poll_management.DASHLETS add column name varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'not set';
```

Comment: I think the query `alter table poll_management.DASHLETS alter column "name" not null;` must be changed to `SET not null`

Answer (score 0):

i found that my query must be change to :

```
alter table poll_management.DASHLETS add column name varchar(255) not null DEFAULT 'value';
```