# PostgreSQL add new not null column and fill with ids from insert statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I´ve got 2 tables.

```
CREATE TABLE content (
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  name text
);


CREATE TABLE data (
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    ...
);
```

The tables are already filled with a lot of data.
Now I want to add a new column content_id (NOT NULL) to the data table.
It should be a foreign key to the content table.

Is it possible to automatically create an entry in the content table to set a content_id in the data table.

For example

```
**content**
| id | name |
|  1 | abc  | 
|  2 | cde  |
```

**data**

```
| id |... |
| 1  |... |
| 2  |... |
| 3  |... |
```

Now I need an update statement that creates 3 (in this example) content entries and add the ids to the data table to get this result:

**content**

```
| id | name |
|  1 | abc  |
|  2 | cde  |
|  3 | ...  |
|  4 | ...  |
|  5 | ...  |
```

**data**

```
| id |... | content_id |
| 1  |... | 3          |
| 2  |... | 4          |
| 3  |... | 5          |
```

Comment: Where do the values `3,4,5` for the new `content_id` come from? What is the logic?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add a column that doesn't allow nulls in a Postgresql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512451/how-can-i-add-a-column-that-doesnt-allow-nulls-in-a-postgresql-database)

Comment: it´s an auto generated id.
The answer doesn´t help, because i am seraching for the statement in the middle of the example:
... some work (set real values as you want)...

Comment: You must describe what exactly you want to do. How do you find the correct content_id? Or do you simply want to add random data?

Comment: For every existing entry in the table data i need to add a new line to the table content and add the auto generated id from the new content entries to the existing data entries.

Comment: How is the name column in the new content records be filled?

Comment: name has a default value ''

Comment: There is no existing link between "data" and "content" so what is the rule to create the foreign key from "content" to "data"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=63fcf1a46dcf96cad71429f99f2e1f2b)

According to the answers presented here: [How can I add a column that doesn't allow nulls in a Postgresql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512451/how-can-i-add-a-column-that-doesnt-allow-nulls-in-a-postgresql-database), there are several ways of adding a new `NOT NULL` column and fill this directly.

Basicly there are 3 steps. Choose the best fitting (with or without transaction, setting a default value first and remove after, leave the `NOT NULL` contraint first and add afterwards, ...)

---

**Step 1**: Adding new column (without `NOT NULL` constraint, because the values of the new column values are not available at this point)

```
ALTER TABLE data ADD COLUMN content_id integer;
```

**Step 2**: Inserting the data into both tables in a row:

```
WITH inserted AS (                -- 1
    INSERT INTO content
    SELECT
        generate_series(
            (SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM content),
            (SELECT MAX(id) FROM content) + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data)
        ),
        'dummy text'
    RETURNING id
), matched AS (                   -- 2
   SELECT
       d.id AS data_id,
       i.id AS content_id
   FROM (
       SELECT
           id,
           row_number() OVER ()
       FROM data
   ) d 
   JOIN (
      SELECT
          id,
          row_number() OVER ()
      FROM inserted
   ) i ON i.row_number = d.row_number
)                                 -- 3
UPDATE data d
SET content_id = s.content_id
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM matched
) s
WHERE d.id = s.data_id;
```

Executing several statements one after another by using the results of the previous one can be achieved using [`WITH` clauses (CTEs)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html):

1. Insert data into `content` table: This generates an integer series starting at the `MAX() + 1` value of the current `content`'s `id` values and has as many records as the `data` table. Afterwards the new `id`s are returned
2. Now we need to match the current records of the data table with the new ids. So for both sides, we use [`row_number()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) to generate a consecutive row count for each records. Because both, the insert result and the actual `data` table have the same number of records, this can be used as join criterion. So we can match the `id` column of the `data` table with the new `content`'s `id` values
3. This matched data can used in the final update of the new `content_id` column

**Step 3**: Add the `NOT NULL` constraint

```
ALTER TABLE data ALTER COLUMN content_id SET NOT NULL;
```